# Error running Xcode Unit Tests from Command Line

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, jenkins

I am trying to run my Xcode unit tests via command-line so I can eventually wire it to Jenkins for CI.  The Workspace contains 2 projects:

**CommonProject (shared libraries used for multiple apps)**

**MainProject**

The MainProject uses libraries in the CommonProject, so there is a dependancy.  Each project has its own separate xcodeproj file.

So I need to run my unit tests associated to the MainProject.  I use this command to run the unit tests from Terminal in the Main Project Directory:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme MainProject -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 -destination OS=7.0,name="iPad"
```

I get the following errors.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/development/MainProject/../../../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MainProject-frbbgalqmolpaxcdmzssejnssluu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/development/MainProject/../../../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DTCoreText-fgbvjplplkeyyghcvrfbmvoetoiq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos'

ld: library not found for -lCommonProject
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** TEST FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MainProject-bxpugeyjdgrcfcgxxpttwlgmfrma/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MainProject.app/MainProject normal i386
```

Since the unit tests require the common project to run, it may not be able to find the files it needs since they are located in a separate directory.  Has anyone had this issue before or have any ideas how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with this issue before and the solution was to ensure the generated library files were in the same location as the `project.app` file. Given this you need to point the CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR to a common location. You can use the argument below to accomplish this.

`xcodebuild test -scheme myScheme -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator7.0` **`CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$(PWD)/build`**

Comment: That worked!  The only additional thing I had to do was set the build location to a shared folder using Preferences -> Locations, Advanced.  I used that location for the configuration_build_dir.  Thanks.